# How to convert String value to Boolean value in Java

Tags: java

I have String values which return via Java Socket. The String values looks like below

```
<command valid="true" /> 
    and 
<command name="LoadDocument" executed="true" />
```

I need to read this Strings and store "valid" and "executed" parts values into Boolean variable. ("valid" and "executed" parts can be true or false). I tried following solution,

```
String str = "<command valid=\"true\" />"; // stored command in a String variable
boolean bool = Boolean.parseBoolean(str); // pass it as an argument
```

but bool value is always false. how can I do this?

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you try [`Boolean.parseBoolean(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-)? *"Parses the string argument as a boolean. The `boolean` returned represents the value `true` if the string argument is not `null` and is equal, ignoring case, to the string `"true"`."*

Comment: @Andreas I tried that. but always it gives "false".

Comment: @KMS Then the string you pass to `parseBoolean()` is not `"true"`. Since you haven't shown us what you've tried, can't help you figure out what you did wrong, but try printing the value, so you can see what text you're trying to parse.

Comment: @Andreas I have stored above command (String command = "<command valid=\"true\" />";) into the String variable and then pass it as an argument to the parseBoolean method.

Comment: @KMS You can't do that. *You* need to parse the "command", in order to extract the value of the `valid` attribute. You can then parse that value to a boolean using `parseBoolean()`. Perhaps if you edit the question and show a bit more of what you're trying to do, and what you've tried, you'll get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use **regexp** [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/azTfEQ/1):

```
private static final String REGEXP = "<command.+(?:valid|executed)=\"(?<val>[^\"]+)\"\\s*\\/>";
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEXP);

public static boolean isValidOrExecuted(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(str);
    boolean matches = matcher.matches();
    return matches && Boolean.parseBoolean(matcher.group("val"));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
System.out.println(isValidOrExecuted("<command valid=\"true\" />"));                            // true
System.out.println(isValidOrExecuted("<command valid=\"false\" />"));                           // false
System.out.println(isValidOrExecuted("<command name=\"LoadDocument\" executed=\"true\" />"));   // true
System.out.println(isValidOrExecuted("<command name=\"LoadDocument\" executed=\"false\" />"));  // false
```

Comment: Why not use a proper tool like an XML reader? Additionally, if the OP has a finite set of possible strings (assuming the input is always trusted), `indexOf`/`contains` is way easier to read than regexps (and faster).

Comment: Yes, ther're many ways to do this. For this simple example - no need to use addition lib (but it does, if you use it more than only for this example). `indexOf` is usually not good, because you can find a wrong part of the line.

Comment: This is why I would first ask the OP to tell whether they trust the input and if they have a finite set of possible input strings. BTW, your pattern **also** relies on an assumption of having the finite set of inputs: say, for instance, if the input doc is new-lined in the middle of the tag right before the attribute, thus the input is still a valid XML document. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags so I would not mind adding a library that does the job right.

Comment: No need to start a combine for two spikelets

Comment: I would say the same for promoting bad habits on programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this safely. First, you have to make sure the string is not null and its value is Here, the case is ignored. So, "true" or "TRUE" will return boolean true otherwise false

```
String str = "true";
String str1 = "ok";
boolean bool = Boolean.parseBoolean(str);
System.out.println(bool);
boolean bool1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(str1);
System.out.println(bool1);
```

> result

```
true
false
```

Comment: I tried this solution, when I pass the above command as an argument to the Boolean.parseBoolean method it always gives "false".

Comment: Please log or debug what you get the value before parsing into boolean. I think it does not get true value that's why it shows false

Comment: @KMS *"when I pass the above command"* The `parseBoolean` method doesn't know anything about your "command". It knows how to parse `"true"` and `"false"`. Extracting the attribute value from the "command" is your job. The "command" looks like XML, so maybe use an XML parser for that?